# An algorithm on $S_n$. What is the final permutation?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This question is inspired by [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/rotate-for-a-max) coding puzzle. I've tried to figure a pattern but couldn't really, but ideally I'd like to see a proof even if I did see it (if it's possible).

Let $\{ \sigma_1,...\sigma_{n-1} \} $ be a family of permutations on $S_n$ defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
    \sigma_j(i)=
    \begin{cases}
      i, & \text{if}\ i\in[1,...,j-1] \\
      n, & \text{if}\ i=j \\
      i-1, & \text{if}\ i\in[j+1,...,n]
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Concretely, $$\sigma_1 = (1\ n\ (n-1)\ ...\ 3\ 2)$$
$$\sigma_2 = (2\ n\ (n-1)\ ...\ 4\ 3)(1)$$
$$\sigma_3 = (3\ n\ (n-1)\ ...\ 5\ 4)(1)(2)$$
$$\sigma_{n-1} = (n\ (n-1))(1)(2)...(n-2) $$

In words, these can be visualized as follows: if the number $123...n$ represents $S_n$, and 'moving to the left' sends the left most digit to the right end, then
$\sigma_1$ moves $123...n$ to the left. $\sigma_2$ fixes $1$ and moves $23...n$ to the left. $\sigma_3$ fixes $12$ and moves $34...n$ to the left. And so on.

For example, in $S_5$, $\sigma_1$ transforms $12345$ to $23451$. $\sigma_2$ transforms $12345$ to $13452$. Etc.

**My question is**: What  does $\sigma := \sigma_n\sigma_{n-1}...\sigma_1$ actually look like? 
The reason I ask is because if we look at the "visualization" I described, we get the following:

$$n=1:\ \ \sigma (1) = 1$$
$$n=2:\ \ \sigma(12) =21$$
$$n=3:\ \ \sigma(123) =213$$
$$n=4:\ \ \sigma(1234) =2431$$
$$n=5:\ \ \sigma(12345) =24153$$
$$n=6:\ \ \sigma(123456) =246315$$
$$n=7:\ \ \sigma(1234567) =2461537$$
$$n=8:\ \ \sigma(12345678) =24683751$$
$$n=9:\ \ \sigma(123456789) =246815973$$

All I wanted, really, was to predict how $\sigma$ transforms $123...n$ in its respective $S_n$. I can see the pattern of all even numbers neatly distributed to the left, but can't really figure out anything for the remainder of the odd numbers to the right. Is this just a conincidence? Because looking at the cycles doesn't actually seem to show a pattern at all...:

$$n=1:\ \ \sigma = (1)$$
$$n=2:\ \ \sigma = (12)$$
$$n=3:\ \ \sigma  = (12)$$
$$n=4:\ \ \sigma =(142)$$
$$n=5:\ \ \sigma =(13542)$$
$$n=6:\ \ \sigma =(156342)$$
$$n=7:\ \ \sigma =(142)(36)$$
$$n=8:\ \ \sigma =(1842)(3576)$$
$$n=9:\ \ \sigma =(156397842)$$

Comment: not a full answer, because I'm not sure it is correct and haven't proved it, but I would conjecture that you can obtain $\sigma(12\cdots n)$ in the following steps: move all the integers in even positions to the left to obtain $s=24\cdots\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor 13\rfloor m$ (where $m=n$ if $n$ is odd and $m=n-1$ if $n$ is even). Split $s$ in half, with $1$ on the left if $n$ is odd to obtain $s=24\cdots\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor t$ or $24\cdots\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor 1t$, where $t$ has length $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ and repeat the process on $t$.